Identify device marked `NY2`
Can anybody identify the component marked NY2 shown in the picture?



Could you measure how long and wide it is?

A zoomed out picture would be helpful to show what it's connect to.

Some manner of multilayer ceramic component: capacitor, NTC, PTC, MOV, inductor, antenna -- need more context and some measurements to know what. What resistance is it (preferably as removed from circuit)? If open, what capacitance?
